# Format C# code in VS 2013 using Roslyn

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, format, roslyn

I'm using Roslyn with VS 2013, and I need an API to format C# code.

The `Formatter.Format` methods require `Workspace` that is available only from Microsoft.Build version 14.0.0.0,

Is there any API in Roslyn that supports C# code formatting for VS 2013??

Comment: You need that inside of a VS 2013 extension?

Comment: Sharper, i develop an app in vs 2013, the app does the code formatting...

Comment: You can use the newer MSBuild API even when compiling from VS 2013

Answer (score 0):

Only the specific type `MSBuildWorkspace` is tied to MSBuild 14.0. You could use `AdHocWorkspace` or your own derivation if you can't take the dependency. You can also [install the MSBuild package](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159) independently rather than having to install all of Visual Studio.

If you're running code *inside* Visual Studio (i.e. you're an extension), you should be using `VisualStudioWorkspace` instead.

Comment: I'm using Roslyn version 0.7.0.0 -  AdHocWorkspace doesn't exists. Can the latest Roslyn version work with VS 2013?

Comment: The latest version of Roslyn is 1.0 (and soon to be 1.1) that you can grab [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis). As far as compatibility -- the core compiler and workspace layer have no Visual Studio dependency, and run on .NET framework 4.5 or higher. MSBuildWorkspace is one exception, and requires the Visual Studio 2015 Build tools package to be installed. It does not require the full Visual Studio install. The VS-specific parts of Roslyn do require VS2015.